# Fetch-request from React frontend doesnt work

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, api, fetch-api

I am making a simple program with a backend in ASP.NET Core Web API, and a frontend in JS React. I have a SQL-database in my backend with a table called Events (*Arrangementer* in Norwegian). The events table has three columns: ID, name, and description.

I have opened and started the react-project. In my App.js (which is the only file I have edited since opening the project), I am trying to fetch some event data from my SQL-database. When I try to console.log() the json-response, nothing gets outputted to the console. I have tried using an ASYNC function, but that doesnt work either. My backend is up and running, and I have data inside of the tables, i can see that when i click the fetch-url.

Here is the App.js file:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch("https://localhost:7031/api/Arrangements")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json)
    })           
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
    
      testing project

      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[The getter in the Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4Rhg.png)

Comment: Add a catch handler to your promise and output any errors - any failure there goes to Nirvana

Answer (score 0):

If you console log the `res`, you will see some response.
But I don't think you can use JSON in the last `.then`, because `res.json()` doesn't save your data anywhere.

Try using a `useState`, and set that state in the last `.then`.

Comment: @FlushBG Thanks, I tried that now. I used setEvents(json) in the last .then, and then console.logged it. Now the is an empty array in the console. Do you have any tips going forward from here?

Comment: you cant set the events to json, since that it's not the value of your response. 
You should be able to set it to res.data or just res, depending on your fetch. 

Remember that the last then always returns, which means if you'll have more than one .then, the last one counts. 
You can use finally() for the last step instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something is wrong with the endpoint. First thing that strikes me is that the url you are using starts with `https://` but adresses localhost. I'm aware that's possible, but are you sure it's not `http://` ?

To be sure of that, please test your endpoint using Postman or the Chrome Dev tools network tab - both should give you sufficient information about the status of your endpoint.

Your frontend code looks good and should work, so I believe you have a backend problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try it plz. Seems your code is fine. If your get response from Backhand(200 in Network Tab) no issues.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';

const MyApp = () => {
    const [service, setService] = useState({})/According to Your API response;
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = "http://localhost:7031/api/Arrangements";
        fetch(url)
        .then(res =>res.json())
        .then(data => setService(data));
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
          <p>{service.length}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyApp;
```